# Rotating points or shape to new axes

Tags: python, math, scikit-image

I wrote some code in Python that fits an ellipsoid to 3D data using the moments parameters returned by [Scikit-Image regionprops function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops). Basically what I've done is gotten the 'inertia tensor' from regionprops, which I feed to [numpy eigh](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) to get eigenvector and eigenvalues. These eigenvectors are orthogonal unit vectors that describe the major and minor axes of an ellipsoid fitting my data (I think). I've cannibalized this idea from Matlab's regionprops3 function - my linear algebra class was over a decade ago and I remember very little from it.

With the data returned from skimage regionprops I can get the equation of an ellipsoid. My issue is that this ellipsoid has its major and minor axes aligned to the xyz axes, not the vectors that describe the true ellipsoid. I need to rotate the ellipsoid so that the major axis is aligned with the first eigenvector (not the x axis) and the minor axes are rotated to second and third eigenvectors (instead of y and z axis).

[A picture will hopefully clear up what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtLTU.png)
Left image is the raw data to fit, right image is the fitted ellipse but not rotated appropriately. I assume by looking at the raw data that the ellipsoid should be aligned more vertically and maybe back (higher y).

I've been grappling with this for a few days but my understanding of matrix algebra and geometry is just not enough for me to make sense of what I need to do here. I thought I could maybe dot product the ellipsoid with the unit vectors but that didn't work. There are rotation matrices, Euler angles, quaternians, gimbal locks, etc. These all seem exceedingly complicated solutions to a (seemingly) simple problem. I've seen some solutions using 'singular value decomposition' but I don't know what that is.

Based on some reading I think what I am trying to do is called 'active rotation of axes transformation' but I just cannot figure this out.

Thank you SO much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay it actually is just a dot product. My issue is that I am plotting in xyz but scikit image returns vectors in zxy. An added issue is that my z-spacing is ~11 times greater than in xy, so it just needs some extra steps.

The rotation array is as I described it in my question:

[[eig1x, eig2x, eig3x]

[eig1y, eig2y, eig3y]

[eig1z, eig2y, eig3z]]

and then you transform all your data with:

new_point = np.dot(rotation_matrix, old_point)